# Need the bot to not heal user if their health is full

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've recently made this "heal" command that increases health by increments of ten when used. However, I'd like to try and cap the health at 100 so users aren't just accumulating it. Below is the code and an attempt I made.

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
  name: "heal",
  description: "heal a user's health by 10",
  cooldown: 120,
  async execute(client, message, args, cmd, discord, profileData) {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('919453438813823017')) return message.channel.send("You aren't a medic!");
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("You need to mention the user you are trying to heal.");
    const Number = 10;
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!target) return message.channel.send("This user does not exist.");

    try {
      const targetData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: target.id });
      if (!targetData) return message.channel.send(`This user doens't exist in the db`);
///
    if(targetData.health = 100) return message.channel.send('This user is at already at max health');
///
      await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userID: target.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            health: Number,
          },
        }
      );

      return message.channel.send(`${target}'s health has been healed for ${Number}!`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    }
};
```

Basically the goal would be that the bot checks the mentioned user's health and if it is at 100, the command cannot be performed on them. Any advice would help.

Edit: The console log gives ReferenceError: targetData is not defined at  `if(targetData.health === 100) return message.channel.send('This user is at already at max health');` . When I execute the command, nothings happens, as opposed to the mentioned user getting healed (their health# is not at 100).

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
  userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
  serverID: { type: String, require: true },
  reputation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  health: { type: Number, deafult: 100},
});

const model = mongoose.model("ProfileModels", profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

```
   let profileData;
    try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if(!profileData){
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                name: message.author.id,
                userID: message.author.id, 
                serverID: message.guild.id, 
                reputation: 0,
                health: 100,
            });
            profile.save();
        }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Except for the '(${targetData.health})' part I see your code fine, have you tried to put a couple of logs and see what pair of logs you can find?

Comment: Pair of logs? Sorry if it's an obvious ask, I'm not very familiar with js.

Comment: Add some console.log with the data u think its wrong. By the way, whats happen when ypu execute the command, and what do you expect?

Comment: The console log gives ReferenceError: targetData is not defined at `    if(targetData.health === 100) return message.channel.send('This user is at already at max health');` . When I execute the command, nothings happens, as opposed to the mentioned user getting healed (their health# is not at 100).

Comment: try to set a  `console.log(targetData)`  after `const targetData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: target.id });` and see what is inside.

Comment: like this?

    try {
      const targetData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: target.id });
      console.log(targetData);
      if (!targetData) return message.channel.send(`This user doesn't exist in the db`);

I still get the not defined error.

Comment: Can you try to get a complete list of the users you have in the database and check that they are returned correctly?

Comment: I figured it out, I used (`if (targetData.health = 100)`) like you advised but instead of one quotation I used three. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Right, if you just use a = it assigns the value, I don't know how I missed that, when using 3 it compares the data and the data type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to check the equality between a variable and a number and not assigning a number to a variable you need to use [double equals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness):

```js
if(targetData.health == 100) {}
```

Comment: I used triple equals before I saw this comment and it worked, do you still recommend I use double?

Comment: With double "100" == 100 will returns true, with triple "100" === 100 will returns false because the type isn't the same, the equality is not perfect. Depends of what you have and want.

Comment: I'll stick with == to play it safe then. Thanks!